# Developing external add-ons for dspace?

Tags: dspace

For a specific technical reason, I am interested in developing some lib outside of Dspace, that would be used in Dspace. However those lib will have some dependency on some dspace class like Item. I am thinking of simply adding things like Dspace-api as dependency during the development of the lib. The lib as to be a separate project from dspace.

What would be the proper way to re-integrate them after, that is, adding the lib as dependency to my Dspace Application. Would simply adding them as dependency to the "overalyed" e.g. Api be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your add-on a maven project.

In its dependencies section, include a dependency to dspace-api of the correct version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dspace</groupId>
        <artifactId>dspace-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Add your add-on as a dependency to `dspace-src/dspace/modules/additions/pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
     <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
     <version>xyz</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

If you're using an older DSpace version and there is no `dspace-src/dspace/modules/additions/pom.xml` file, I believe it will work to add the dependency to `dspace-src/dspace-api/pom.xml` instead. You will then need to use the full build option.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance here. Yes Working on 1.8.2 unfortunately can't change it

Comment: Cool, try the dspace-api pom, if that doesn't work then I guess ask again and mention that you're stuck on 1.8.2. ;)

Comment: You can make your own "additions" module in 1.8.x the same way it exists in later versions, just make sure to include it in the right places (modules pom, xmlui pom)